# i18n, javascript - is there a way to use a 2nd file for the differences?

Tags: javascript, internationalization, i18next

I would like to use, as I am doing now, one file for my primary language and a second file for english.
This is working great.

Now I would like to add two more files. One with just the changes compared to the primary language and a second one for the other language.

In other word..the first file is a big file with all the dictionary but for a specific customer i need some words to be translated differently. Instead of writing another file 99% equal to the original I just would like to write the different words.

How can I do that?

this is my code:

```js
var i18nextInstance = i18next
  .use(i18nextXHRBackend)
  .use(i18nextBrowserLanguageDetector)
  .init(
    {
      detection: {
        // Escludo localStorage. Praticamente ricorda l'ultima lingua usata.
        //order: ['querystring', 'cookie', 'localStorage', 'navigator', 'htmlTag'],
        order: ['querystring', 'cookie', 'navigator', 'htmlTag'],
      },
      fallbackLng: 'en',
      lng: lingua_attiva,
      debug: false,
      ns: ['common'],
      defaultNS: 'common',
      backend: {
        loadPath: './i18n/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json',
        crossDomain: true,
        parse: function (data) {
          // queste 3 righe sotto mi fanno utilizzare il json che include anche la lingua.
          // infatti, nel caso di un file per lingua, la lingua non andrebbe messa. Solo che ci sono delle estensioni
          // come quella di PHP che la vogliono lo stesso. Per questo la lascio e la escludo.
          try {
            var json = JSON.parse(data); // --> { en: {  ... } }
            var m = Object.keys(json); // --> ['en']
            return json[m[0]]; // --> { common: { ... } }
          } catch (e) {
            alert(e); // error in the above string (in this case, yes)!
          }
        },
      },
    },
    function (err, t) {
      // initialized and ready to go!

      // Se in ingresso non avevo passato nessuna lingua, la imposto adesso con quella rilevata
      if (lingua_attiva == undefined) {
        lingua_attiva = i18nextInstance.language.substr(0, 2);
      }

      // Se la lingua non è tra quelle abilitate, forzo inglese
      if (lingua_attiva != 'it' && lingua_attiva != 'en') {
        lingua_attiva = 'en';
      }

      ConfiguraMainWebsite();
      AggiornaTraduzioni();
    }
  );

// Configuro le opzioni per utilizzare jquery nelle traduzioni
jqueryI18next.init(i18nextInstance, $, {
  tName: 't', // --> appends $.t = i18next.t
  i18nName: 'i18n', // --> appends $.i18n = i18next
  handleName: 'localize', // --> appends $(selector).localize(opts);
  selectorAttr: 'data-i18n', // selector for translating elements
  targetAttr: 'i18n-target', // data-() attribute to grab target element to translate (if diffrent then itself)
  optionsAttr: 'i18n-options', // data-() attribute that contains options, will load/set if useOptionsAttr = true
  useOptionsAttr: true, // see optionsAttr
  parseDefaultValueFromContent: true, // parses default values from content ele.val or ele.text
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new file with diffs only (this means that the keys are the same as in the `common` file), let's call it `diffs` and use i18next [namespace fallback](https://www.i18next.com/principles/fallback#namespace-fallback) feature.

In a specific place you can use `diffs` namespace (which will load `diffs.json` file) and fallback to your `common` namespace for missing keys.

Since your config is already defined `common` as a `defaultNS`, all you need to do is just for the specific user change the namespace to `diffs`.

```
<div class="outer" data-i18n="diffs:key"></div>
// -----------------------------^

$(".outer").localize();
```

You can define the namespace for a specific region of translation

```
$(".outer").localize({ns: 'diffs'});
// this will call translation on the `.outer` div with a specific namespace without the need to attach it as I've showed before
```

Comment: Great, it works, thank you! I just have a last question. Let's say I will have the file "common.json" with everything, then I create customer1.json and customer2.json. when customer1 logs in I need to add to i18n only the file for customer1 otherwise the other file. How can I add the "ns" dynamically and set defaultNS dinamically?

Comment: https://www.i18next.com/overview/api#loadnamespaces - adds new namespace
https://www.i18next.com/overview/api#reloadresources